# Android Camera Parameter - Mono Effect

Tags: android, colors, mono, camera, effect

Hi I am trying to capture images in black and white, while I was searching the google I notice that the android camera has a parameter like the mono effect.

I used like this:

```
Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
param.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_WHITEBOARD);
cameraObject.setParameters(param);
```

But there is a problem, this is not Black and White, there are  grey tones also, I just want two colors ! The Black and the White ! Is there any way to do it? How?

Thanks alot in advance !

Comment: have you found the solution? than pls share your solution !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it

[Take monochrome picture (black and white) with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040526/take-monochrome-picture-black-and-white-with-android)

If someone has a better/faster solution please tell me :)

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

It is called `Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO` for "monochrome" which is the technical term for "black and white".