# Can I take Black and White pictures using android camera intent?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera-intent

Is it possible to take pictures in black and white using camera intent ? I tried camera that taken color pictures.

Comment: You can for sure convert a color image to a grayscale version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be achieved using an intent.

If you want black and white, you'll have to use

`setColorEffect(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO);`

but of course, this isn't using an intent.

You could take a look here explaining algorithms to take a monochrome picture. But it's a longer way.

[Take monochrome picture (black and white) with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040526/take-monochrome-picture-black-and-white-with-android)